# Chrome Extension - Validate Selected Text Before Creating Context.Menu

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got the context.menu working correctly. I just don't want it to show whenever I select something other than an IP address. I have the code for validating a IP address just don't know how to implement this.

I know that chrome will add context.menus when you select hostnames and ip addresses and add "go 98.223.234.2xx" or "go cnn.com". How is chrome doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is

1. Use `mouseup` and `keypress` event listeners for mouse and keyboard selection, respectively.
2. Use `window.getSelection()` to get the selection, and compare it with the IP address you want.
3. If the selection matches the IP address, you can create the menu by

   ```
   chrome.contextMenus.create({
     "title" : "menuTitle",
     "contexts" : ["selection"]
   });
   ```